# Google Drive folder with dual boot Windows10 / Ubuntu16.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10, google-drive, grive

I am planning to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on dual boot alongside with my already existing Windows10. Right now, pretty much all the files I use are in a single folder (let's call it `myFiles`) synchronized between my Windows10 computer and my Google Drive account.

What I want to do :

- Keep access to `myFiles` from Windows10
- Be able to access `myFiles` from my future Ubuntu partition
- Have `myFiles` synchronized between my Google Drive account and my computer 
  (whether I am working from my Windows 10 or future Ubuntu partition)
- Avoid troubles !

I used Grive on my Virtual Box before to synch a folder from Linux to Google Drive and it worked fine. Also, my hard drive is large enough (1TB) to give a lot of space to my future Ubuntu partition if necessary.

Should I :

1 - Give just about 30GB (like in most tutorials) to my Ubuntu partition and share my Google Drive folder with my old Windows10. In that case would my files still get synchronized when I'm booted in Ubuntu?

2 - Give a lot of space (over 100GB) to my Ubuntu partition, replicate my files on both my partitions, and keep working with Grive on Ubuntu. In that case, I'm sure my files would be synchronized from both my partitions.

It's the first time I dual boot my computer. Any advice is welcome!